# Having troubles facing my cat the other way on key press

Tags: javascript

Trying to face my fat on it's direction of the keyPressed event. I do not understand what I am doing wrong.

```
function draw(){
  background(sky);  
  keyPressed();
  rect(0, 470, 900, 55);
  image(sun, 40, 0, 900, 500, -900, -500);
  image(catL, plrX, plrY, 100, 100);
  image(catR, plrX. plrY, 100, 100);
  if(lookingLeft == true)
  {
    catL = catL
  }
  if(lookingRight == true)
  {
    lookingRight = true
    catL = catR;
  }


}

function keyPressed(){
     if(keyCode === LEFT_ARROW){  
       plrX = plrX-5; // move left
       lookingLeft = true;
     } 
     if(keyCode === RIGHT_ARROW){  
       lookingRight = true;
       plrX = plrX+5; // move right

     } 


}
```

Cat starts facing left, and then when I click RIGHT key it works, but DOES NOT turn back to the left after I click again.

Comment: Ah, this is from some coding site. Please specify that and link to the actual task

Comment: You need to call the image AFTER the test and do something like  `if(cat == catR)  {  cat = catL } else   { cat = catR;  }` and start with cat = catL INSIDE the keyPressed and inside keyPressed you call draw with `image(cat, plrX, plrY, 100, 100);`

Comment: Does not work. It does not change the image back.

Comment: Did you change the cat inside the key pressed instead of the draw?